# Reused tableView cells not calling layoutSubviews method

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a custom `tableViewCell` class and within my tableView cell I have a custom `UIView`.  Each tableView cell is associated with a unique `UIBezierPath` that is set equal to the views `path` property.  In order to render the path, `layoutSubviews` has to be called.  I noticed that `layoutSubviews` is getting called for my first 5 cells, but the next 5 cells do not call `layoutSubviews` so their paths do not end up being rendered and they just end up reusing the paths of the first 5 cells.  Since the second 5 cells are just reusing the first 5 cells, how can I call `layOutSubviews` for each cell?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString* identifier = @"audioTableCell";

    OSAudioTableCell *cell = [self.audioTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
         cell = [[OSAudioTableCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: identifier];
    }

        Recording * recording = [self.managedDocument.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.waveView.path = nil;
        cell.waveView.minAmpl = [recording.minAmpl floatValue];
        NSData * pathData = recording.waveData;

        //Setting the path 
        cell.waveView.path = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:pathData];
        [cell setImageSize:cell.waveView.bounds.size];
 }
```

//This is the first method in my custom UIView class waveView that gets called

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{

    if (!self.blueWave) {

         self.blueWave = [self createShapeLayer];

         self.blueWave.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:107/255.0f green:212/255.0f blue:231/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;

        self.redWave = [self createShapeLayer];
        self.redWave.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        self.redWave.strokeEnd = self.progress;

        [self.layer addSublayer:self.blueWave];
        [self.layer insertSublayer:self.redWave above:self.blueWave];

        [self render];

    }

}
```

Comment: It's critical that you call `[super layoutSubviews]`

Comment: where would I call this?

Comment: As the first line of your layoutSubviews.

Comment: @rmaddy Implemented it but it didn't make a difference. if I call [self.waveView layOutSubviews]; in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it will call the method for each cell which is good.  However, the second set of 5 cells will each render the correct path and the path of the cells they are reusing.

Comment: Never call layoutSubviews directly.

Comment: @rmaddy  Hmm how can I have the method called for each cell and set the path of the reused cells view to nil?

Comment: Override the cell's prepareForResuse method and set the path property to nil.  And instead of calling layoutSubviews directly just call setNeedsLayout and let UIKit decide when to update the layout.

Answer (score 0):

So `layOutSubviews` was not getting called for my reused cells no matter what I tried.  I attempted to set the `UIView` path to nil then calling `setNeedsLayout` but that did nothing.  I tried clearing the path in `prepareForReuse` but still no luck.  What I had to do was manually remove the the `CAShapeLayers` whenever a cell was reused.  That did the trick.

```
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[OSAudioTableCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: identifier];
}
else
{
    [cell.waveView.blueWave removeFromSuperlayer];
    [cell.waveView.redWave removeFromSuperlayer];
    cell.waveView.blueWave = nil;
    cell.waveView.redWave = nil;
    cell.waveView.path = nil;
    cell.trackLabel.text = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles across this answer now and has the same issue:

I fixed it by putting the function that calculates the new path of the layer in a separate DispatchQueue block in the override layoutSubviews() function within the UICollectionViewCell class.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: viewBubbleBase.bounds, cornerRadius: bubbleCornerRadius).cgPath
    }
}
```